# pandas equivalent of R's make.names

Tags: python, pandas

R has a very useful function `make.names` that can change the `names` of a column to be well-behaved AND unique. I have a situation where I am reading data from a csv file and there can be multiple columns with the same name. R's `make.names` function can give unique names by appending `.1` , `.2` to the names etc.

Is there a similar function in python / pandas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a separate function, or do you only need the behaviour?  `read_csv` does this by default:

```
>>> !cat nonunique.csv
a,a,b,b,b,2,2
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
8,9,10,11,12,13,14
>>> df = pd.read_csv("nonunique.csv")
>>> df
   a  a.1   b  b.1  b.2   2  2.1
0  1    2   3    4    5   6    7
1  8    9  10   11   12  13   14

[2 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: hmmm....want to add this to http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_r.html ?

Comment: @DSM, good to know. unfortunately, i needed the behavior because I have some 40 csv files each with 600+ columns with no headers and each has a separate file that contains the headers. i read the csv files using `read_csv` but then I have to read the separate file with headers and then assign them. but this function `make.names` is easy to write, so no worries.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the `pd.read_csv` doesn't exactly match the R `make.names` functionality. Specifically when I want to use a pandas data frame in an R script it usually fails.

You can use `rpy2` however to get that functionality directly:

```
from rpy2 import robjects  
good_names = list(robjects.r['make.names'](robjects.vectors.StrVector(bad_names)))
bad_to_good_converter = {bad_names[i]:good_names[i] for i in range(len(bad_names))]
```